# How can I use other methods between different groovy scripts

Tags: selenium, groovy, automation, webdriver

I'm trying to automate a website through groovy scripts, but I'm kind of stuck where I'm trying to call a method in another groovy script. I'm trying to call `LoginWebsite()` found on the `Login` groovy script on the `MainControl` groovy script, but I keep getting the following error `Cannot invoke method LoginWebsite() on null object`

I'm unsure as to what I'm doing wrong and would like some help

Login class:

```
class Login
{
def projectContext = context.testCase.testSuite.project.context;
def driver = projectContext.driver;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

public boolean LoginWebsite()
{
    try
    {       
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("mainLoginBtn"));
        (new Actions(driver)).moveToElement(element).perform();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        element.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);     
        driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys(testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("ID"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("pin"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("loginBtn"))));
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginBtn")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        log.info(ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
}
context.setProperty("LoginStep",new Login())
```

MainControl class

```
for(String website : wList)
{
    //ChromeDriver property setters are global variables 
    //CD - ChromeDriver     CDL - ChromeDriverLocation
    //website is website URL's
    System.setProperty(com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue("CD"),com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue("CDL"));
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    def projectContext = context.testCase.testSuite.project.context;
    projectContext.driver = driver;
    driver.navigate().to(website);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    def lib = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("Automation_groovy").getTestCaseByName("Website_Auto").getTestStepByName("Login")
    lib.run(testRunner,context)

    def login = context.LoginStep;
    boolean s = login.LoginWebsite();

    if(s == true)
    {
        log.info(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: The message tells you `login` is `null`.

Comment: @Guy I've commented out in `Login` the `class Login` and `public boolean LoginWebsite()` to whether the if i run it on it's own (note that I also commented it out any code that is trying to use `Login` methods in the `MainControl`). It is working on it own and I'm getting back true. Why I'm getting `null` instead of a `true` or `false` when i do it with classes or trying to call the script inside another

Comment: this generally happens when class code fails. you can try printing context.LoginStep. it will not get printed. So there is some problem in the class code that you have to debug.. Try to paste that code as normal code without class or you can comment out full code inside the class to check out where is the problem